# C# efficient ContainsAll with duplicates?

Tags: c#, .net

Similar to existing "ContainsAll" methods but specifically I want to check that any duplicates from the sublist are also present in the main list.
eg. I have some lists:

```
List<int> a = new List<int> { 1, 2, 1, 3 };
List<int> b = new List<int> { 1, 1, 2 };
List<int> c = new List<int> { 2, 2, 3 };
```

What I want is a function `bool ContainsAll(List<T> l1, List<T> l2)` such that `ContainsAll(a, b) == true` (since the duplicate 1's are common to both lists) but `ContainsAll(a, c) == false` (since list a doesn't have multiple 2's).

I could of course search manually through the main list, removing the items as I find them. However this would require duplicating the list (since I don't want to modify it) and I was hoping for a cleaner/faster approach if one exists.

ETA: I need to check that the quantity of each element found in the larger list is at least as many as in the smaller list. Not merely that there are multiple in both lists, but that each element from the smaller list can be paired with a unique element in the larger list.

I don't have a specific performance requirement. I really just want to know if there is a more "correct" way than the manual check. You could argue that "correct" may mean faster, or more readable, or simply easier to write by using inbuilt functions. Maybe there isn't a better way. I will add that my use case may involve checking the larger list against several smaller lists, so a one-time transformation of the larger list (eg. to a dictionary) is certainly a consideration.

Comment: So, a "Contains 2 or more"? Or do you plan to build a list of only the duplications from both list, then run a Contains All check?

Comment: Since fast version of Contains requires building some sort of hash table.... I don't get why you believe doing the same manually will somehow use more memory/be slower... A single function call is not O(1) operation... Some [edit] to clarify performance expectations/requirements would help.

Comment: Christopher: The choice of a pair is arbitrary to keep the example small. If the second list contains 100 copies of a given item, the first should contain at least 100 if the function returns true. Will edit for clarity.

Comment: Alexei Levenkov: Interesting, I assumed it could simply run through the existing list as an O(n) operation. If no faster approach exists, then that would answer my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could count each element of both lists, and then check that the counts of all elements in `l2` is less than or equal to the corresponding count in `l1`.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

static Dictionary<T, int> Count<T>(List<T> l)
{
    Dictionary<T, int> c = new Dictionary<T, int>();
    foreach (var o in l)
    {
        if (!c.ContainsKey(o))
            c[o] = 1;
        else
            c[o]++;
    }
    return c;
}

static bool ContainsAll<T>(List<T> l1, List<T> l2)
{
    Dictionary<T, int> c1 = Count(l1);
    Dictionary<T, int> c2 = Count(l2);
    foreach (var kvp2 in c2)
    {
        // If c1 doesn't contain the current value
        // or its count is < the current value's count in l2
        // return false
        if (!c1.ContainsKey(kvp2.Key) || c1[kvp2.Key] < kvp2.Value)
            return false;
    }
    // All checks were successful, return true
    return true;
}
```

[Try it online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/VGK5sq)

Of course, this approach involves building a dictionary, so you sacrifice memory for speed, but it'll be faster than checking using `List.Contains()` because looking up in a list is O(n)

Comment: This is a nice idea. A Dictionary seems like a more readable way to store data with duplicates anyway (in a case where the order doesn't matter but quantities are important). I could consider using it in the first case for my specific application, rather than a List whose order was unimportant to me.

Comment: If you need order to matter, a sorted dictionary may help

Answer (score 0):

If you make your `a` a lookup, you can then ask if it contains all `b`'s keys at a greater than or equal count

```
var al = a.ToLookup(x=>x);
return b.ToLookup(x=>x).All(ble => al.Contains(ble.Key) && al[ble.Key].Count() >= ble.Count());
```

You can optimize this by building only one set of counts, then checking it can "pay" for the second set of values

```
var d = new Dictionary<int, int>();
a.ForEach(x => { if(d.ContainsKey(x)) d[x]++; else d[x] = 1;});

b.ForEach(x => { if(--d[x] < 0) throw new Exception($"More {x} in B than A"); });
```

In this latter line of code one of two things could happen:

- the dictionary built from `a` does not contain the key from b - a keynotfoundexception arises
- the count dips below zero (the `--d[x]` returns the new value stored in the dictionary. If it is negative there are more of key x in b than a and a different exception arises

Thus if the exception arises b is not a subset of a. If it doesn't, it is

You can change it to be exceptionless if you want by expanding the second ForEach to a foreach  loop and doing `if(!d.ContainsKey(x) || --d[x] < 0) return false;` in the loop and `return true` outside the loop..

Comment: An interesting approach. I don't much like the idea of throwing exceptions, that feels wrong when I actually just want to return false. The latter suggestion seems more logical/readable.

Comment: I suppose it depends how often subsets will arise. Maybe a huge majority of the time they are subsets and you want to skip the extra checking/are prepared to let an exception arise that you catch and return false. If a huge majority of the time they are are not subsets then the exception approach will hit performance hard because it will throw a lot and avoiding them would improve things. It's the sort of thing only you can assess (and it shouldn't be done on "feeling" but instead a reasonable estimate of how often subsets will arise and what the best performance will be, tested even)

Comment: All in I would expect the high cost of an exception to outweigh the ContainsKey in many cases, but I don't even know how often this method will be called- if it's once a day you can take a very different approach to it than if it's called several times a second